# Why aren't these styles resulting in a single-line header and centered page contents?

Tags: html, css

I am not *that* bad at this, but somehow i am not able to center the contents of the page.

Also, the `logo` and `tbar-right` `div`s are not aligning properly (I'd like them to be arranged in a single line).

This is my markup:

```
<body>
<div class = "container">
  <div id="topbar" >

    <div class="logo">
      <img src="images/rg-logo.jpg"/>
    </div>

    <div class="tbar-right">
      <div id="User"><!--the script will feed this div--></div>
      <!--Dummy Text-->Jasdeep, you have 24 routemiles&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="#">My Profile</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="#">Logout</a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
</body>
```

...and these are the styles:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body{
    -x-system-font:none;
    background:#FFF;
    border:0 none;
    color:#555F6A;
    font-family:Verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:0.7125em;
    font-size-adjust:none;
    font-stretch:normal;
    font-style:normal;
    font-variant:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:1.5em;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;

    }

#topbar {
    background-color: #df3e36;
    height: 32px;
    width: 1004px;
    }

.logo {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    width: 15%;
    height:27px;
    }

.tbar-right {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-top: 7px;
    width: 85%;
    }

.tbar-right a{
    color: #FFF;
    }
```

Please, help!

Answer (score 2):

```
.container{margin:0 auto;}
```

As long as you have defined an explicit width. You should also probably replace

```
<div class = "container">
```

with

```
<div class="container">
```

Comment: container is a class and not an Id.

Answer (score 1):

Should center container. Make sure you don't float it.

```
.container{
 width: /* must specify a width */
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}
```

This should fix the alignment

```
.logo{
float:left;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-top: 4px;
width: 15%;
height:27px;
}

.tbar-right{
float: right;
padding-right: 10px;
color: #FFF;
padding-top: 7px;
width: 85%;
}
```

And you may need to rearrange the HTML a bit by putting the .tbar-right before the .logo

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#topbar { margin: 0 auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The logo isn't aligning with the other stuff because it has a different padding-left. Change to

```
.logo {
    padding-left: 0px; //or don't even list a padding-left,
    padding-top: 4px;
    width: 15%;
    height:27px;
    }
```

OH if you wanted it on the same line horizontally float them both to the left or right, and make sure there's enough space. ;D